# ImportError: No module named 'pkg_resources' in builds on readthedocs.org

Tags: python, read-the-docs

I started building docs for a project of mine with readthedocs, and it was working great for a while, but now I get this crazy error:

```
Collecting sphinx==1.3.5
  Using cached Sphinx-1.3.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Pygments==2.1.3
  Using cached Pygments-2.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting setuptools==20.1.1
  Using cached setuptools-20.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting docutils==0.12
  Using cached docutils-0.12-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting mkdocs==0.15.0
  Using cached mkdocs-0.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting mock==1.0.1
Collecting pillow==2.6.1
Collecting readthedocs-sphinx-ext from git+https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs-sphinx-ext.git@0.6-alpha#egg=readthedocs-sphinx-ext
  Cloning https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs-sphinx-ext.git (to 0.6-alpha) to /tmp/pip-build-dpx17gw2/readthedocs-sphinx-ext
Could not import setuptools which is required to install from a source distribution.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/pyee/envs/latest/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 372, in setup_py
    import setuptools  # noqa
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/pyee/envs/latest/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from setuptools.extern.six.moves import filterfalse, map
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/pyee/envs/latest/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/extern/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pkg_resources.extern import VendorImporter
ImportError: No module named 'pkg_resources'
```

Do I need to install setuptools somehow? Is that even possible? My module was using setuptools before and it was fine; what changed?

**EDIT:** This is on the public service, not on my localhost.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can install setuptools python package or you can download the package extract it and simply place it in site-packages of your python installation directory or in the location of your pythonpath

Comment: Linux commad for setup tools:- 
"pip install -U pip setuptools"

                                                    
Note:-If you have Python 2 >=2.7.9 or Python 3 >=3.4 installed from python.org, you will already have pip and setuptools, but will need to upgrade to the latest version

Comment: If you don't have root access then you need to do local installation

Comment: this is not a local installation, this is the public service.